# Retrieve varchar as url link from SQL Server to Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to retrieve a varchar from SQL Server to create an `Url.Action` in Razor asp.net.

The SQL cell looks like this:

```
"Index","Contact"
```

The code in the razor view looks like this:

```
href=@Url.Action(carousel.Link)
```

The result in the browser looks like this:

```
href="/Home/%22Index%22%2c%22Contact%22"
```

The desire result is:

```
href="/Contact"
```

Any ideas of how to escape those weird characters?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The data in your database is wrong. It would need to be `/Contact/Index`in order to work in `@Url.Action()`. But in any case the controller and action names should be stored separately

Comment: %22's are double quotes. May be you could try Url.Encode for correct url handling.

Comment: You can use string.split to extract the 2 items and use string.join to build the desired output (after reversing the order)/concatenate it as needed. But as stephen suggested ,you should be fixing the way you store the data.